# The interface class method does not save the file to the selected folder

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt

There was a problem with saving the file to the specified path. Here is a part of the code that is not executed until the end (i.e. it receives a response from the server, and then silence, although a dataframe should be formed for subsequent saving to a file):

```
# accepting the server response
    def recv_msg(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        rep_file = data.to_csv('report_df.csv', index=False)
        target_fld = self.get_folder()
        os.path.join(str(target_fld), rep_file)
        print('file upload')
        self.sock.close()
```

Here is all the code in the module:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import pickle
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from upload_client_gui import Ui_MainWindow

class gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

        self.download_folder = None
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_msg)

    # selecting the date of the report to be uploaded
    def calendar_date(self):
        date = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        string_date = str(date.toPyDate())
        return string_date

    # the file explorer opens to select the folder where the file will be saved
    def get_folder(self):
        try:
            self.download_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select a folder to save')
            os.chdir(self.download_folder)
            print(self.download_folder)
        except:
            pass

    # sending a date to the server via a socket
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.calendar_date()
        print(msg)
        self.sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

    # accepting the server response
    def recv_msg(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        rep_file = data.to_csv('report_df.csv', index=False)
        target_fld = self.get_folder()
        os.path.join(str(target_fld), rep_file)
        print('file upload')
        self.sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = gui()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The folder selection works, the absolute path is returned, the socket request and response are also there.

Please help me figure out where my problem is.

In the version without GUI, the socket works properly.

Comment: You are calling `to_csv` **after** you call `get_folder()`, which, by the way, returns absolutely nothing. Besides, you should not use `chdir` just because you want to save a file in a specific path: use the full path. For that, you could use `os.path.join`, but certainly not like you did since: 1. it's returned value is never used; 2. as said above, `get_folder()` returns nothing, so `target_fld` will be `'None'`.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the tip. I figured out `chdir` and `get_folder`. But please explain in more detail how to make the `os.path.join` part correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistakes! It was necessary to put sending and receiving messages in one method, and slightly rewrite the creation of a file in the selected folder. I hope it will be useful to someone:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import pickle
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from upload_client_gui import Ui_MainWindow

class Gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

        self.download_folder = None
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_folder)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_msg)

    # selecting the date of the report to be uploaded
    def calendar_date(self):
        date = self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        string_date = str(date.toPyDate())
        return string_date

    # the file explorer opens to select the folder where the file will be saved
    def get_folder(self):
        try:
            self.download_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select a folder to save')
            self.download_folder = self.download_folder.replace('/', '\\') + '\\'
        except:
            pass

    # sending the date to the server and receiving information from the server via a socket
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.calendar_date()
        self.sock.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

        data = self.sock.recv(10240)
        data = pickle.loads(data, encoding='utf-8')
        try:
            target_fld = self.download_folder
            data.to_csv(os.path.join(str(target_fld), 'report_df.csv'), index=False)
            self.sock.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Gui()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Note that there's absolutely no need to replace the directory separator, as Python is completely capable of handling the standard forward slash even under Windows. You also don't need to add a further separator, as `os.path.join` automatically does it.

Comment: @musicamante, I'm not a wizard, I'm just learning))) thanks for the advice, I will continue to study.

Comment: I didn't mean my comment as paternalizing, I was just pointing out aspects of your code that are important to be aware of: even if they don't affect nor disrupt the behavior of your program, it's important to realize them. The usage of "\" as directory separator in Windows has created **a lot** of issues in programming for **decades**, and it's **not** nor can be considered a standard (no matter the diffusion of MS systems). The conventional directory separator is `/` (as it is for web URLs, which *is* a quite important standard). Both Qt and Python follow it, so you can safely use it.